# New Moon Armor pieces locations in The Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

What are the locations of the pieces that make the New Moon Armor in The Witcher 3?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- *New Moon Armor* = in a tower near **Crane Cape** sign post, on the island north-west of Novigrad
- *New Moon Gauntlets* = inside the ruins east of **Heddel** sign post, north-east of Oxenfurt
- *New Moon Boots* = inside the ruins east of **Kilkerinn Ruins** sign post, north-east of Oxenfurt
- *New Moon Trousers* = on top of the ruins south-east of **Vikk Watchtower** sign post, north-east of Oxenfurt

[image]